# wxPython Poor Frame Resolution

Tags: wxpython

This is a screenshot of a frame made with wxPython on Mac OS X (Retina)

[image]

Why is the resolution so poor ?

Comment: Which wxPython version are you using?

Comment: I contend there is no really universal support for HiDPI in wxPython/wxWidgets yet, [see this ticket for example](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/16116). If you need HiDPI today, use pyQt5.

Comment: I am using version 3.0